# How to check if a noun exists in a text file with C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I have tried to find a library in C# that can help me do parts of speech tagging to recognize a noun from a sentence but with no avail. So I decided to check my string's words against a list of nouns in a text file I downloaded. My code assumes the first Noun in a sentence is the noun referred to by the verb, I assumed this because most comments left on a website do not compose of many words. So here is my attempt at splitting the text to an array and then looping through each noun in the noun.txt file and see if my string exists. My code is below, I just want to return `The first noun found` or `No noun detected` as the return type of my methods.

```
string DetectNoun(string param){
  //split the input parameter into words based on spaces
  string[] words=param.ToLower().Split(" ");
  //read all the nouns in the text file into an array:NB all nouns are in lower case
  string[] allNouns=File.ReadAllLines("Nouns.txt");
  //loop through each noun in the array and check if any exists in our input parameter
  int j=0;
  for(int i=0;i>allNouns.Length;i++){
   if(allNouns[i]==words[j++]){
      //return this word as the noun found
       return allNouns[i];
     }
  }
  //if no match was found return no noun detected
  return "No noun detected";
}
```

Tested that above with a sample input of `Samsung Television, No manual, Box included`. It keeps returning `No noun was detected` despite television being in the text file of Nouns I just downloaded.

Comment: You are splitting the words by space, so the word `Television` in your sentence becomes `Television,` (with a comma at the end), so it doesn't match. Also, you are doing `==` to check, which is by default case sensitive on strings, and even if it wasn't, it's not very clear whether you are checking for reference or content equality there... you should use `string.Equals()` and pass a string comparer to check for equality (e.g.: `string.Equals(allNouns[i], words[j++], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`), but that alone won't help your exact case here

Comment: Also, why are you reading the whole file list into memory for each line you're checking?

Comment: @DM, the `Television` is converted to lower in this call `string[] words=param.ToLower().Split(" ");`

Comment: @TechGeek Yeah, I missed that the first time, thanks

Comment: @jcl, I think am doing `television,==television`

Comment: Got it, am gonna replace all the comas with nothing and then split into an array with space, Thanks Guys

Comment: @TechGeek, nope, you are doing `television, == television`. Check it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nDIXJD

Comment: Replacing all the commas with `""` is going to work

Comment: Your for loop is broken, too. `if(allNouns[i]==words[j++]){` with each `i` you are incrementing `j`, too.

Comment: Yes... I'd replace all non alphanumeric characters (except for space), just to be sure (, but you'll need to check if that suits your input (something like `Regex.Replace(input, @"[^a-zA-Z\d ]", "");`)

Comment: Also guys, the nouns in the text file are each on a new line, using `File.ReadAllLines()` will cause each word to be eg `Arctic\n`

Comment: @Fildor, what corrections do you propose I implement to my code?

Comment: @TechGeek nope, `File.ReadAllLines()` does not include line feed or carriage return on the resulting strings

Comment: You need to evaluate each entry against the whole list, don't you? Right now, you are returning the first match in words in the same index. Plus: this will crash if your file contains more entries than the word list.

Comment: @Fildor, yes that is wat I want to do, check if an entry exists in the list, if not return `not found`

Comment: But you do not. You are comparing index by index, not : "First entry in A that exists in B". You are checking "First entry in A that exists _in the same index_ as in B".

Comment: @TechGeek I'd do it with linq if performance is not of extreme importance and/or the datasets are small, something like: `return allNouns.FirstOrDefault(x => words.Contains(x)) ?? "No noun detected";`, however that wouldn't help you understand it if I just wrote that as an answer, would it :-)

Comment: @Jcl, I understand the expression, it looks like ternary operator with a return. That is a clever shortcut. implementing that in my solution

Comment: `??` is the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator).

Comment: Not ternary, but null-coalescing (if `FirstOrDefault()` returns null, then the right part, else the result). Check it here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2diiva

Comment: @DM, I am trying that out now. I hope it will work

Comment: it is returning box instead of television. I expect it to return, wait. that is because the list is alphabetical. But it should return television because it comes before box on my sentence input

Comment: @TechGeek just switch the comparison: `words.FirstOrDefault(x => allNouns.Contains(x))` ( https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZjRhHo ). On the above version I had reversed the `words` and `allNouns` variables

Comment: @Jcl, okay. Trying it out. Thanks

Comment: I'll write an answer with all of this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original code has a couple problems:

1. You are splitting by space, so in your case, you get (for example), `television,` with a comma in your word list. When comparing, you are comparing `television` with `television,` so it doesn't match.
2. You are using `==` for a comparison, which is "confusing" when comparing strings, you should rather use a correct string comparer.
3. Your `for` loop is broken, you are only comparing index to index (first word with first noun, second word with second noun, etc.)... also, if your noun list is smaller than your word list, this will raise an `IndexOutOfRange` exception

To solve all of these:

1. Remove all characters from your string that you don't want, prior to splitting. I'd recommend a regex (`Regex.Replace(input, @"[^a-zA-Z\d ]", "")`, but you'll need to check whether that suits your input (specially if receiving non a-Z alphanumeric characters, like accents, or umlauts, etc.)
2. Use StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase or StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase instead of going `ToLower()`. `ToLower()` is usually not the right way to do it specially when doing cultures other than English
3. I'd use Linq and make a one-liner out of it:

```cs
words.FirstOrDefault(x => allNouns.Contains(x, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

That'd return `null` if the no word in `words` is contained in `allNouns`, otherwise, the first match.

Putting it all together:

```cs
string DetectNoun(string param){
  string[] words = Regex.Replace(param, @"[^a-zA-Z\d ]", "").Split(' ');
  // You should cache this somewhere if you plan to call this many times,
  // but I'll leave that up to you
  string[] allNouns=File.ReadAllLines("Nouns.txt");
  return words.FirstOrDefault(x => allNouns.Contains(x, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
            ?? "No noun detected";
}
```